# How to avoid having 3 nested foreach and write better code?

Tags: php, refactoring, code-cleanup

I am getting some data from a big json file which is full of nested arrays.
I am in a situation where I need 3 ugly foreach and I would avoid, if possible, to have such a garbage code but cannot figure out how to refactor it in a more decent way.

This is the code:

```
  $isFinalSale = [];
  foreach($orderCachedResponse->fulfillments as $fulFillment) {
    foreach($fulFillment->line_items as $line_item) {
      foreach($line_item->properties as $propertyEntry) {
        if($propertyEntry->name === '_final_sale') {
          array_push($isFinalSale, $line_item->id);
        }
      };
    };
  };
```

Comment: An example of the data might help us help you. Otherwise this looks like a perfectly likely method of accessing a deep array or arrays

Comment: If you needed to handle dynamic nesting you could use `array_walk_recursive()`. But for just 3 levels of nesting, this is the normal way to do it.